# What does custom exception print each letter of argument?

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3, I can pass an argument into an exception and print it out the same:

```
try:
    raise Exception('my exception')
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex.args)
```

> ('my exception',)

If I define a custom exception, it prints each letter as an argument.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Networkerror(RuntimeError):
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.args = arg

try:
   raise Networkerror('Bad hostname')
except Networkerror as e:
   print(e.args)
```

> ('B', 'a', 'd', ' ', 'h', 'o', 's', 't', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`args` attribute of `BaseException` is documented to be a `tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args), but you assigned a plain `str` to it. This happens to work because `str`s are iterables of their characters; when unpacked for printing, they look the same as a `tuple` of single letters. You can wrap in a single element `tuple` to fix:

```
class Networkerror(RuntimeError):
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.args = arg,
```

or accept positional varargs that produce a `tuple` implicitly:

```
class Networkerror(RuntimeError):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      self.args = args
```

or just not define `__init__` on the subclass and let the base class handle it normally (usually the correct solution when you have no special arguments you need to handle yourself):

```
class Networkerror(RuntimeError):
    pass
```